# Issues mining on a HD 6850

Tags: mining

I've been trying to put an old card into use into my PC. However I can not get it to start mining, After I installed the drivers I launched xmrig-AMD and tried to start mining however after detecting the gpu it just hung, did not respond the keyboard. After closing it and reopening the computer BSODed and gave the error: "thread stuck in device driver". I've tried other miners such as xmr-stak and all fail to start mining. I've also tried attaching a monitor to the gpu but to no avail. I can't think of anything else to try, is the card dead? I can just use it for normal usage though so I can't understand why I can't mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm mining with HD 6950 in Windows 7 x64 and xmr-stak 2.1.0 using the drivers 14.1 beta, download drivers here: http://www.guru3d.com/files-details/amd-catalyst-14-1-beta-1-6-(13-350-1005-january-31).html

Remember to use an app like MSI Afterbuner to regulate the fan and clocks (I don't recommend to OC), my card is hot and is the reference card so I have to set the fan to 55% and the card does not reach 65°

I get: ~300 h/s

**EDIT:**

You can download [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/2403r6x7nie7pml/xmr-stak-2.1.0-amd-old.zip) the binary that I compiled with VS 2017, I didn't modify anything, I just compiled using the guide provided in xmr-stak github, I think it works because I installed the latest AMD APP SDK, with the binary provided from the official github I also get 90 h/s

Comment: Probably correct but seems like my graphics card has a hardware issue, I'm going to shove it in the oven and pray. Or as techies call it I'm going to reflow the card

Comment: Are you getting artifacts? Download [this](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) program to list the BSODs to see if it comes from the card, I forgot to mention one important think, is that I compiled xmr-stak, let me know if you are insterested so I can give the one that I'm using

Comment: no artefacts just a black screen when installing drivers. I seem to have gotten it working by cooking it for 8 minutes at 190 Celsius. Ghetto fixes ftw. I appear to only be getting 40h/s with a max overclock so would appreciate to learn how you got 300.

Comment: I compiled it, when I get home I will provide the compile that I'm using, remember that you may not get 300

Comment: much appreciated but I hope I can reach a little higher than 40h/s

Comment: answer updated with the link, let me know if it worked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71840/discussion-between-joss-bird-and-tttony).